# Tools that allow to write markdown, latex and R code (knitr) in the same document and convert to pdf?

Tags: markdown, latex

I have been searching the internet for hours but I think I am looking in the wrong direction. *Hopefully this is the right place for asking, otherwise please point me in the right direction :)*

I write markdown documents. I use latex inside these documents for equations and figures. I save these as .txt and use pandoc to convert to .pdf and such,

```
pandoc example.txt -o example.pdf --bibligraphy library.bib
```

to be precise. I have now started using knitr as well. I played around with it for a bit and tried to create more markdown .txt documents with latex embedded (as described above) as well as R code chunks. I then converted this to .pdf using pandoc but this didn't produce the desired result.

**My question: are there any tools that will allow me to write markdown, latex and Rcode (knitr) in the same document and convert to proper pdf (and .docx) versions?**

Comment: It would reallly help to know how the results differed from your desired results.

Comment: Do you want to typeset these R code chunks, or do you want to execute them and typeset their output (graphs?)?

Comment: There is a workaround if you use [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) instead of markdown. It supports embedded Latex and R code snippets, and its syntax is similar to markdown and easy to learn. Documents can be directly exported to pdf from within Emacs.

Comment: @SteveBarnes It just didn't look nice. I sorry that is very vague, but what happened was that the R code/R markdown wansn't understood by pandoc as such an it turned it nonsense.

Comment: @Gilles, I want to both typeset the R code chunks as well as typeset their ouput (graphs)

Comment: @rosannav I have added a note and link on how to do R in ipython. Unless you tell ipython that a cell is R with the magic it will be assumed to be either python or Markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at the ipython [notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html).

It lets you mix via your browser

- Markdown
- Formulae with MathJax
- Python code
- R code
- Several other programming  languages
- Bash Scripts
- The results of all of the above including graphs etc
- Syntax highlighted code in 100s of other languages

It allows export as html and pdf as well as sharing as notebooks.

- Free and open source.
- Cross Platform.

**You will need to install r2py and use the rmagic command as explained [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/extensions/rmagic.html)**.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I'm going to look into that